# How to shorten response scrolling window in .pynb inside vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter

If I were to get a large output in a locally hosted Jupyter notebook, I could simply click the sidebar of the given cell, which would put the output in a shorter, scrolling window.  I'd like the same or similar functionality in vscode.  I've only found the option to use the Jupyter shortcut 'o', but that hides the output and doesnt even leave a marker to show the cell has a hidden output (which I think could become really frustrating).  I haven't been able to find any other extensions/packages, probably because the Python extension in vscode supports Jupyter.  Any ideas?

**vscode version 1.14.2**

[image]

Comment: Which versions of vscode and jupyter? Mine outputs to a shorter, scrolling window (truncating excessive output since I'm using code-server rather than just vscode).

Comment: Hey @HansMusgrave, I've added the info

Comment: I think the cutoff for a scrolling block is larger than for vanilla jupyter. Does `print('a'*10**4)` cause a scroll bar to appear?

Comment: yes, it does!  Wondering if there is a way to adjust that setting.  Have you seen anything like nbextensions that can be used in vscode?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to adjust it (or minimize the output), nbextensions don't seem likely ever, and it might take a little while before any kind of extensions are supported. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7954